# Turning Printed Answers into a List

Tags: python, list, printing, sum, range

My goal is to have all values on the range(11) that are divisible by 2 be available in a list in order to find the sum.  Here's my current code:

```
y = list(range(11))
for x in list(range(11)):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
    else:
        print(0)
```

My output looks like this:

```
0
0
2
0
4
0
6
0
8
0
10
```

Comment: So put them into a list instead of printing them. What exactly are you stuck on? Have you read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an empty list variable and  append the items to the declared list through `append` function.

```
L = []
y = list(range(11))
for x in list(range(11)):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        L.append(x)
    else:
        L.append(0)
print(L)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what does the L = [] mean in terms of the code?

Comment: we assigned an empty list at the start to `L` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
y = list(range(11))
for x in list(range(11)):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        a.append(x)
    else:
        print(0)

print (a, sum(a))
```

or just do this:-

```
l = [x for x in range(11) if x%2==0]
print (l, sum(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
results = []
y = list(range(11))
for x in y:
    if not x % 2:
        results.append(x)

print 'Numbers divisible by 2: {}'.format(results)
print 'Sum of results: {}'.format(sum(results))
```

Output:

```
Numbers divisible by 2: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
Sum of results: 30
```